# Is Cain really the father of all vampires as he is cursed to drink his brother's blood, which may assimilate the essential feature of vampires.

Tags: hebrew-bible, bible-versions

I was every now and then accumulating the description that Cain is the father of all vampires as I constantly read various tales though some of them are not really strictly quoted from the authoritative publications. So I wonder if there's any proof or fact that he is the one as I personally presume the curse on him to drink Abel's blood from God as the evidence.

Comment: Please add at least the reference for the curse.

Comment: It was fairly obvious which text the user was referring to - so an edit has been proposed with that verse included - as well as suggesting a new title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this question out of scope, but still try to give an answer just to fight this myth.

There is no such curse. Read Gen 4, especially verses 10 and 11:

> 10 The Lord said, "What have you done? Listen! Your brother’s blood cries out to me from the ground. 11 Now you are under a curse and driven from the ground, which opened its mouth to receive your brother’s blood from your hand. 
>   It is the ground's / earth's mouth that received / drank the blood."

Biblically, there is no evidence for vampires either. On the contrary, consuming blood is forbidden in the old covenant.

> But you must not consume the blood. You must pour it out on the ground like water. Deu 12:16 (also see Gen 9:4, Lev 7:26, 17:10, 19:26 and more)

in the new covenant, the same holds true:

> Instead, we should write and tell them to abstain from food polluted by idols, from sexual immorality, from the meat of strangled animals, and from blood. Acts 15:20 (also see verse 29)

Paul tells us that we can eat anything, which would include meat with blood in it, but certainly not allow for drinking blood.

> So you may eat any meat that is sold in the marketplace without raising questions of conscience. 1Co 10:25

Comment: Sometimes whether a question is out of scope can be unclear, especially for novice contributors, but if you "find this question out of scope" the last thing you should do is answer it.  And if you are not sure, a wise course of action is to wait a few hours to see if other think it is out of scope.